# How can I solve nested counter?

Tags: android

I wrote this app which counts from 0 to 9. In logcat when I run this and click on the screen it counts normally, but when I double click on the screen it becomes a Nested Counting. How can I solve it so that whenever I click the button it starts counting from 0 and stops the previous counting Thread

```
package com.example.test;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Do Time Consuming : ");
        setContentView(button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        runTh();
    }

    public void runTh() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        System.out.println(i);
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Here is the logcat:

```
2019-03-18 21:26:57.752 32757-32757/? I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2019-03-18 21:26:58.269 32757-32757/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2019-03-18 21:27:00.238 32757-32757/com.example.test I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
2019-03-18 21:27:00.954 32757-310/com.example.test D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
2019-03-18 21:27:01.335 32757-310/com.example.test I/zygote: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-03-18 21:27:01.336 32757-310/com.example.test I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2019-03-18 21:27:01.337 32757-310/com.example.test D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2019-03-18 21:27:01.340 32757-310/com.example.test W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2019-03-18 21:27:01.340 32757-310/com.example.test D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
2019-03-18 21:27:01.366 32757-310/com.example.test D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe0384e00: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
2019-03-18 21:27:01.372 32757-310/com.example.test D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe0384e00: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe03a8ca0)
2019-03-18 21:27:01.445 32757-310/com.example.test D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe0384e00: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe03a8ca0)
2019-03-18 21:27:04.567 32757-316/com.example.test I/System.out: 0
2019-03-18 21:27:05.569 32757-316/com.example.test I/System.out: 1
2019-03-18 21:27:06.571 32757-316/com.example.test I/System.out: 2
2019-03-18 21:27:07.573 32757-316/com.example.test I/System.out: 3
2019-03-18 21:27:07.592 32757-317/com.example.test I/System.out: 0
2019-03-18 21:27:08.576 32757-316/com.example.test I/System.out: 4
2019-03-18 21:27:08.595 32757-317/com.example.test I/System.out: 1
2019-03-18 21:27:09.578 32757-316/com.example.test I/System.out: 5
2019-03-18 21:27:09.596 32757-317/com.example.test I/System.out: 2
2019-03-18 21:27:11.971 32757-316/com.example.test I/System.out: 6
2019-03-18 21:27:11.973 32757-317/com.example.test I/System.out: 3
2019-03-18 21:27:12.897 32757-318/com.example.test I/System.out: 0
2019-03-18 21:27:12.974 32757-316/com.example.test I/System.out: 7
2019-03-18 21:27:12.975 32757-317/com.example.test I/System.out: 4
2019-03-18 21:27:13.899 32757-318/com.example.test I/System.out: 1
2019-03-18 21:27:13.977 32757-316/com.example.test I/System.out: 8
2019-03-18 21:27:13.978 32757-317/com.example.test I/System.out: 5
2019-03-18 21:27:14.901 32757-318/com.example.test I/System.out: 2
2019-03-18 21:27:14.979 32757-316/com.example.test I/System.out: 9
2019-03-18 21:27:14.980 32757-317/com.example.test I/System.out: 6
2019-03-18 21:27:15.902 32757-318/com.example.test I/System.out: 3
2019-03-18 21:27:15.982 32757-317/com.example.test I/System.out: 7
2019-03-18 21:27:16.904 32757-318/com.example.test I/System.out: 4
2019-03-18 21:27:16.985 32757-317/com.example.test I/System.out: 8
2019-03-18 21:27:17.906 32757-318/com.example.test I/System.out: 5
2019-03-18 21:27:17.987 32757-317/com.example.test I/System.out: 9
2019-03-18 21:27:18.908 32757-318/com.example.test I/System.out: 6
2019-03-18 21:27:19.911 32757-318/com.example.test I/System.out: 7
2019-03-18 21:27:20.912 32757-318/com.example.test I/System.out: 8
2019-03-18 21:27:21.915 32757-318/com.example.test I/System.out: 9
```

Comment: you can have your new thread as a variable and halt it upon clicking again.

Comment: can you please write that code for me?

Comment: Add a Thread object as your instance/class variable. Assign newly initiated Thread object to it. I am sure you can find resources for how to halt thread. Don't forget to check if thread is already initialized or not;

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use Thread class instead of RxJava you can save thread instance and stop it before starting new one

Comment: it doesn't allow to solve the problem. It's rather a comment than an answer.